# Google Charts Using SharePoint List Data

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, google-visualization, sharepoint-list

I'm stumped and need a little bit of help

What I want to do is use Google Chart API to create a simple bar graph(chart) that will pull data from a Share Point list.

Here is Google Bar Chart Code....

```
<html>  
<head>    
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">      
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});      
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);      

   function drawChart() {        
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Month', 'Year', 'Number Of Days'],          
   ['Dec',  2013,      10],          
   ['Jan',  2013,      6],          
   ['Mar',  2012,       22],          
   ['Jun',  2011,      44]        ]);        
   var options = {          
   title: 'Company Performance',          
   vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}        };        
   var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));             
   chart.draw(data, options);      }    

   </script>  
   </head>  
   <body>    
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

This works but it is static and I need dynamic data coming from a SharePoint list. Here's the method I used to pull the data from a SharePoint list but can't seem to figure out the best way to get the Google Chart to use my data. Thank in advance.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready( function() {

var siteUrl = "//serverURL",
    listId  = "{b2b61446-4dfc-44f0-80af-8d18b2b17547}";

$.get( siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List=" + listId, 
function( xml ) {
    var zrow = xml.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
    for(var i=0; i<zrow.length; i++) {
        $("#table1 tbody").append( 
        "<tr><td>"
        + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Month")
        + "</td><td>"
        + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Number_x0020_Of_x0020_Days") 
        + "</td><td>"
        + zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Year")  
        + "</td></tr>"
        );
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: Is your second code snippet a sample of code that works for pulling data from your sharepoint list?

Comment: Yes the second piece of code works and pulls data from the SharePoint list...no problem there. I'm just having a hard time trying to figure out...How can i include that code so that it works with the code above it(Google Chart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to thank Asgallant for the response. It was his reposense that prompted me to explore other ways or options to get this to work. Using HighCharts I came up with the following resolution to pull data from a SharePoint list using  XML and JQuery. Check it out. By the way this works for both the Bar Chart and Pie Chart for HighCharts. All you need to do to flip the charts from Bar chart to Pie chart is change the options in the "plotOptions" of the code, where it says [bar]...change to [pie].

By the way, the underscore.js file can be downloaded  from GITHib.com or just do a google search on underscore.js. Another thing....I haven't tested this with over versions of JQuery or SPServices so it might be important to just used what's already been tested here in this example.

Cheers!

And now the code.....The example is based on a custom list of Time Off Request for employees.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Style Library/High Charts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Style Library/High Charts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Style Library/High Charts/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Style Library/High Charts/underscore.js"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">    

$(document).ready(function () {         

$().SPServices({            
operation: "GetListItems",            
CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Employee'/></OrderBy></Query>",            
CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='Day_x0020_Off_x0020_Taken'/><FieldRef Name='Request_x0020_Type'/><FieldRef Name='Time_x0020_Off_x0020_Description'/><FieldRef Name='Employee'/></ViewFields>",            
listName: "{2fdbe305-a489-4428-a319-b4167b8dbabf}",        
completefunc: processData        
});    
});     


function processData (xData, status) {        
var torData = []; 

$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function () {            
    torData.push({                
        timeOff:        $(this).attr('ows_LinkTitle'),                
        dayOffTaken:       $(this).attr('ows_Day_x0020_Off_x0020_Taken'),                
        requestType:     $(this).attr('ows_Request_x0020_Type'),
        timeOffDescription:    $(this).attr('ows_Time_x0020_Off_x0020_Description'),            
        employee:   $(this).attr('ows_Employee')            
    });        
});         



var chartData = [];        
var employeeData = _.groupBy(torData, 'employee');  

 _.each(employeeData, function(row) {            
var empCount = row.length;

    chartData.push( {                
        name:   row[0].employee,                
        y:      empCount            
    });         
});         


renderChart (chartData);    

}


 function renderChart (data) {        
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({            
        chart: {                
            renderTo: 'torChart',                
            plotBackgroundColor: null,                
            plotBorderWidth: null,                
            plotShadow: false            
    },            
    credits: {                
        enabled: true            
    },            
    title: {                
        text: 'Employee Time Off'            
    },            

    plotOptions: {                
        bar: {                    
            allowPointSelect: true,                    
            cursor: 'pointer',                    
            dataLabels: {                        
                enabled: true,                        
                color: '#000000',                        
                connectorColor: '#000000',                        
                formatter: function()    {                            
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y +' Times';                        
                }                    
            },                
        }            
    },            
   series: [{                
        type: 'bar',                
        name: 'Days Off Taken',                
        data: data            
      }]        
   });    
  }


  </script>
  <div id="torChart"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @CBanks I want to  create also Chart. Here Is my Question link :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47374924/sharepoint-2016-dynamic-chart-fro-sp-list-or-excel-sheet. Please have a look at that. I am just starting development on SharePoint. So please Help me step by step guide . Here is my gmail id : mmaid786@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
function drawChart () {
    var siteUrl = "//serverURL",
        listId  = "{b2b61446-4dfc-44f0-80af-8d18b2b17547}";

    $.get(siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List=" + listId, function( xml ) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Month');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Number of Days');

        var zrow = xml.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
        for (var i = 0; i < zrow.length; i++) {
            data.addRow([zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Month"), parseInt(zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Year")), parseInt(zrow[i].getAttribute("ows_Number_x0020_Of_x0020_Days"))]);
        }

        var options = {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            vAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
}
```

That will duplicate the layout of the chart you posted above, but I'm not sure that it is exactly what you want.  That puts months on the vAxis and years as a data series.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Thanks for the work on this! I haven't tried the code above yet but looks like that just might do it. As far as the vAxis I can play around with that to get the correct result - much appreciated. Last thing...I'm assuming all I need to do to call this is  wrap my JQuery  $(document.ready()) around the complete function?  Being that I need this to load then the page loads and I'm stuffing this in a content editor webpart in SharePoint. Cheers!!

Comment: You don't want to run this on document ready; the API may not be finished loading by then, so you want to call it in the callback from the google loader (like your first example).