# SharePoint 2016 Dynamic Chart fro SP list or Excel sheet

Tags: sharepoint

I want to create Dashboard(Chart Library) via Visual Studio on SharePoint 2016.
My SharePoint Configuration:
1. VM
2.Windows server 2012 R. 
3.SQL Server 2014
4.SharePoint server 2016.
5.Visual Studio 2017

In VM I have no internet due to company security policy.

My Requirement: 
1.Upload excel and update dashboard automatically.
2.Update SharePoint list and update dashboard automatically.

I R&D on Google and found so many sites like:

1. http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/visualizing-sharepoint-google-charts/
2. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/dashboardchart-from-sharepoint-list-or-spreadsheet
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-business-intelligence-bar-charts-from-sharepoint-list-view-using-client-s/

I do not know where is my mistake. So please let me know how can I solve the issue and create DashBoard.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

http://www.evoketechnologies.com/blog/visualizing-sharepoint-google-charts/

In this link you need to internet connection on VM.